# Can't Permanently Disable Touchpad

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

I know there are many other posts and forums concerning this, but I tried most of their suggestions and can't get it to work.

I got a new laptop and installed a fresh Ubuntu 16.04. I don't like the trackpad because I like mice better and I don't like it when the trackpad interferes when I'm typing. I've seen posts that ask how to turn it off only when typing, but I really just want it off permanently.

The two most common answers I've seen are:
1.) Toggle the on/off switch under "Mouse & Touchpad" in Settings.
2.) Type `xinput list`, then `xinput set-prop DEVICEID "Device Enabled" 0`

Neither of these worked, but they did both *temporarily* disable the mouse, but if I touched it a certain way it would start working again. It's hard to describe, but I have a feeling that I might have multiple touchpad drivers or something.

This is the output from `xinput list`, I tried disabling 13 but I didn't want to mess around with it too much and break anything.

```
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ Logitech M545/M546                        id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ ALP0011:00 044E:120C                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
        ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ HP HD Camera                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I don't want to physically disable/unplug the touchpad because I don't want to go ripping apart my new laptop.

Thanks

Comment: From [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/787434/616451), does `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events disabled` in a terminal work?

Comment: That did work, but after I rebooted it stopped working entirely, even after rerunning the command.

Comment: Ahh, sorry that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to use:

```
xinput disable 13
```

Try this first at the terminal every time you boot. If you are happy then put it in Startup Applications.