# Touchscreen stops working a few seconds after login to Gnome/Ubuntu session (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: drivers, gnome, xorg, touchscreen

I cannot manage to make my touchscreen to work properly on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04. On the login screen I can still touch the screen to select the user and the password edit box. Even in the first few seconds after login to Gnome/Ubuntu desktop the touchscreen stays responsive for a few seconds but then stops working (just enough time to start a terminal..)

**Informations**

- Laptop/Convertible: [HP Spectre x360 13-4230ng](https://www.notebookcheck.net/HP-Spectre-x360-13-4230ng.174899.0.html)
- Touchscreen: SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 (according to `xinput` and `evtest`)
- Driver used in the xorg-server: `libinput` (I tried `evdev`, but then even the touchpad did not respond anymore, so I switched back to libinput)

To me this seems like a strange problem with the Xorg driver, but I cannot figure out what's wrong.

Using `evtest` I found out that the touchscreen sends signals as long as the Xserver of the Gnome/Ubuntu session is not started yet. After that it does not send signals anymore.

The fact that I had the touchscreen working during the first session makes me quite sure that there should be a fix for this, or at least a workaround. Maybe there are some configuration files that were created during the first start of the Gnome/Ubuntu session? I tried to remove ~./config/dconf/user, but this did not help. Are there any others? Is there another Xorg driver that I could try?

Just to add some more information I append the relevant part of my Xorg.log here:

```
[    17.425] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse (/dev/input/event4)  
[    17.425] (**) SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"  
[    17.425] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse'  
[    17.483] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 31 paused 0  
[    17.484] (**) SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse: always reports core events  
[    17.484] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"  
[    17.484] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"  
[    17.487] (II) event4  - SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse  
[    17.487] (II) event4  - SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse: device is a pointer  
[    17.488] (II) event4  - SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse: device removed  
[    17.488] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:06CB:16F9.0001/input/input13/event4"  
[    17.488] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 10)  
[    17.488] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"  
[    17.488] (**) SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0  
[    17.488] (**) SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000  
[    17.488] (**) SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4  
[    17.490] (II) event4  - SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse  
[    17.490] (II) event4  - SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse: device is a pointer  
[    17.491] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)  
[    17.491] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.  
[    17.491] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.  
[    17.492] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 (/dev/input/event5)  
[    17.492] (**) SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04: Applying InputClass "libinput touchscreen catchall"  
[    17.492] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04'  
[    17.493] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event5 13:69 fd 32 paused 0  
[    17.493] (**) SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04: always reports core events  
[    17.493] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"  
[    17.493] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"  
[    17.496] (II) event5  - SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen  
[    17.496] (II) event5  - SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04: device is a touch device  
[    17.496] (II) event5  - SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04: device removed  
[    17.496] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:06CB:16F9.0001/input/input14/event5"  
[    17.496] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 11)  
[    17.496] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"  
[    17.496] (**) SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04: (accel) selected scheme none/0  
[    17.496] (**) SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000  
[    17.497] (**) SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4  
[    17.499] (II) event5  - SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen  
[    17.499] (II) event5  - SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04: device is a touch device  
[    17.500] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 (/dev/input/mouse1)  
[    17.500] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.  
[    17.500] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

Comment: Guessing: maybe it's something to do with settings to disable touchpad while typing?

Comment: @int_ua: Good idea, but it doesn't seem so. The touchscreen becomes irresponsive before any keyboard typing.

Comment: If you have enough time and disk space you can try installing other desktop environment to check if the issue is isolated to gnome. Not sure if it will work in `openbox` which is one of the smallest ones. KDE should work but will take a lot of space.

Comment: Indeed, in openbox the touchscreen works: I can position the mouse pointer and click on things by touching them. But, whats wrong then with Gnome?

Comment: Try comparing outputs of `xinput --list-props` in openbox and gnome. Get touchscreen id with `xinput --list`. If it's just disabled, try `xinput --enable`.

Comment: The output is exactly the same in openbox and gnome. Both times the touchscreen is enabled according to xinput. `xinput --enable` does not help in gnome. Could it be that the touchscreen driver crashes due to some request by gnome? I even checked KDE-Plasma now, but I see the same problem there (Actually it worked during the first KDE session but then stopped working in the second in the same way as in gnome).

Comment: Maybe you will find some clue in logs: `journalctl -b -x`, `dmesg --ctime`, `less /var/log/Xorg.0.log`, `less ~/.xsession-errors`. That's a lot of text and I'm afraid I can't help with reading it.

Comment: I've just upgraded to 20.04 and my touchpad is disabled on the start too. I've submitted a bug report about it here, maybe it will be helpful for you too https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1876991

Comment: In the meantime I switched from Gnome to Cinnamon desktop. There my touchscreen is working nicely. Not really the solution that I wanted, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: For me the reason of the issue is that I wasn't in the `dialout` group. What mostly likely happened is that I didn't have permissions to read the serial port of the wacom/Touchscreen combo I have. [This is the SO answer which was useful for me.](https://askubuntu.com/a/210230/1123229) Edit: I am using a ThinkPad X201T

Comment: @xeliba any luck to resolve the issue. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @UmairSaleem No, I stayed with Cinnamon desktop since then. Touchscreen works like a charm on that one.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1876991

Marking it as affecting you too will increase chances it will be noticed. Also you can subscribe for updates there.

If your touchpad is set to be disabled with mouse you can try these settings:

**GNOME**: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events enabled` command, Details: [How do I disable touchpad when using a mouse](https://askubuntu.com/q/787433/20275)

**KDE**: System Settings > Input Devices > Touchpad > Enable/Disable > Ignored Devices > Add your "mouse" touchpad/touchscreen entry, should be already filled in as it's "connected".

Comment: Tried this in Gnome but it doesn't help for my touchscreen. To be more precise, actually, I cannot find a subsection "org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchscreen". So i only tried "....touchpad send-events enabled". Anyway, thanks for you efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm quite new here an can't comment on your post yet as it's not unlocked yet.

But i face the very similiar issue with Ubuntu 20.04 and Gnome 3.36.1 with the `HP spectre x360 13-4203ng` in my case.

I welcome any kind of help or idea or request to debug and find the issue, as i'd really like to have the touchscreen working again.

Thanks for all your support - Jack

Comment: Is it 4203 or 4230? Do you see a "mouse" in `xinput --list` with a name similar to your touchscreen? Do you have `psmouse serio1` errors in kernel log (`dmesg -l err,warn` output)?

Comment: It's the `4203` and xinput --list gives me:
⎜   ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse id=10 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04  id=11 [slave  pointer  (2)]

And dmesg -l doesn't give me psmouse outputs. Any idea what else to try? Thanks @int_ua

Comment: Find the output of `dmesg | grep -i serio1` [here](https://echo.notable.md/8f1b09e3329bb674c58ba9d37d00688690882b2e)

Comment: Ok, it looks like it's this bug, at least you have it as a mouse too: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1876991 Marking it as affecting you too will increase chances it will be noticed. Also you can subscribe to updates there. Is your touchpad set to be disabled with mouse? Try `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events` command, Details: https://askubuntu.com/q/787433/20275

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Lenovo Yoga S1.

I noticed in journalctl -b:

```
systemd[1]: Starting Firmware update daemon...
fwupd[2737]: ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/esys_context.c:69:Esys_Initialize() Initialize default tcti. ErrorCode (0x000a000a)
fwupd[2737]: 21:37:44:0499 FuEngine failed to add udev device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/0003:06CB:7244.0003/>
fwupd[2737]: 21:37:44:0675 FuEngine device 602b0a6cc821d155208724f0e22f8d111542b74c [SAMSUNG MZ7TE128HMGR-000L1] does not define a vendo>
systemd[1]: Started Firmware update daemon.
```

I noticed 06CB:7244 is:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 06cb:7244 Synaptics, Inc. Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04
```

I tried blacklisting plugin synaptics-rmi in /etc/fwupd/daemon.conf:

```
BlacklistPlugins=synaptics-rmi;test;invalid
```

But it did not help. In the end I did:

```
sudo apt remove fwupd
```

I guess that's not the best way to solve the problem but it worked!