# Touch screen is not responding well - DELL-Inspiron-5559 - Ubuntu - 20.04

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, touchscreen

Touchscreen is working properly in windows 10, but not in Ubuntu 20.04.(Dualboot)

```
G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]



vijayreddy@v-Inspiron-5559:/$ xinput list-props 6
Device 'Power Button':
    Device Enabled (168):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (170): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (288): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (289):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (290):    0, 0
    Device Node (291):  "/dev/input/event3"
    Device Product ID (292):    0, 1


vijayreddy@v-Inspiron-5559:/$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP              id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Mouse                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 3D Camer           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 3D Camer           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
vijayreddy@v-Inspiron-5559:/$ 

vijayreddy@v-Inspiron-5559:~$ journalctl -b | grep Touch
Aug 26 11:18:45 v-Inspiron-5559 kernel: usb 1-7: Product: Multi-Touch by G2TSP
Aug 26 11:18:45 v-Inspiron-5559 kernel: usb 1-7: Manufacturer: G2Touch
Aug 26 11:18:45 v-Inspiron-5559 kernel: input: DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-DLLC6B2:00/0018:06CB:75BF.0001/input/input8
Aug 26 11:18:45 v-Inspiron-5559 kernel: input: G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/0003:2A94:5241.0002/input/input10
Aug 26 11:18:45 v-Inspiron-5559 kernel: hid-generic 0003:2A94:5241.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input0
Aug 26 11:18:45 v-Inspiron-5559 kernel: hid-generic 0003:2A94:5241.0003: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input1
Aug 26 11:18:50 v-Inspiron-5559 kernel: input: DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-DLLC6B2:00/0018:06CB:75BF.0001/input/input13
Aug 26 11:18:50 v-Inspiron-5559 kernel: input: G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/0003:2A94:5241.0002/input/input15
Aug 26 11:18:50 v-Inspiron-5559 kernel: hid-multitouch 0003:2A94:5241.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input0
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP (/dev/input/event7)
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (**) G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: Applying InputClass "libinput touchscreen catchall"
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP'
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (**) G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: always reports core events
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) event7  - G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) event7  - G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: device is a touch device
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) event7  - G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: device removed
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 10)
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (**) G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: (accel) selected scheme none/0
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (**) G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (**) G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) event7  - G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) event7  - G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP: device is a touch device
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP (/dev/input/mouse2)
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad (/dev/input/event6)
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (**) DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad'
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (**) DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad: always reports core events
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) event6  - DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) event6  - DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) event6  - DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad: device removed
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 14)
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (**) DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (**) DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (**) DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) event6  - DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) event6  - DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad: device is a touchpad
Aug 26 11:19:59 v-Inspiron-5559 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1605]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse1)
vijayreddy@v-Inspiron-5559:~$ journalctl -b | grep Calibrator
vijayreddy@v-Inspiron-5559:~$ journalctl -b | grep Calib
Aug 26 11:18:45 v-Inspiron-5559 kernel: Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 4800.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=9600000)
vijayreddy@v-Inspiron-5559:~$
```

Comment: opening and closing the lid works , but only for sometime a minute or so.

Comment: Same as https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1876991

Comment: Pleae let me know if any DELL laptop user tried this "sudo apt remove fwupd",

Comment: Pleae let me know if any DELL laptop user tried this "sudo apt remove fwupd", from                   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234975/touchscreen-stops-working-a-few-seconds-after-login-to-gnome-ubuntu-session-ubu

Comment: Is there a way to disable the mouse in Ubuntu 20.04, i use only Touchpad.https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1876991