Dconf, touchpad and mouse problems on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I have a laptop (Lenovo Thinkbook 15G2 if that make a difference), where I use a Bluetooth mouse. So far so good.
But I've hands problems so I want to disable the touchpad when I use the mouse in order to be more comfortable.
For this, I've the touchpad enabled in the "preferences" and I've set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events to disabled-on-external-mouse
using dconf editor.
IT works the first time I apply the configuration, and the touchpad is disabled when I turn the Bluetooth mouse on. But if the mouse disappear (power off or Bluetooth disconnect) the touchpad is not put back into use.
And if I log out and back in, the touchpad is disabled in the Preferences and the Dconf disabled-on-external-mouse value return to the default "enabled"....
This annoys me a lot because it make my computer not friendly to my poor hands.
So all help I could get will be very appreciated !
Have a nice and bright day.

This may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/787433/how-do-i-disable-touchpad-when-using-a-mouse and if not https://itsfoss.com/disable-touchpad-when-mouse-used/

Hi, Both links advise about either using touchpad-indicator or modifying Gnome properties (either by the command line or by using the dconf editor). Touchpad-indicator does not work on Wayland (was so when I switched to Wayland, and still is). Modifying the Gnome properties is the way I used since switching to Wayland a long time ago. What puzzle me is why it ceased to work on MY laptop given it works fine on my wife's laptop where the sole difference is the make of the Bluetooth mouse.
So how can I tell what's wrong on my machine ?

Hi
Today tests : I checked that my touchpad and mouse worked just after boot and before login in OK.
Then I turned the mouse off and logged in. No touchpad. Turned the mouse on and checked that the gnome property was properly set up. Then I opened the preference panel and set the cursor in the touchpad config part. I then turned off the mouse. Still no touchpad. I then enabled it using the keyboard cursor movement (arrows and space, tab, return ) to switch it on. IT turned on instantly.
